# Return value of function in UNIX

Tags: function

I do not understand the following expression.

```
function abc(){

..............

...............

[[ -f $filename]] && return 0 || return 1

}
```

As per tutorial if there is a file exists with filename variable name then this function returns 1 otherwise it returns 0.

I understand `&&` `||` operator ,but how is this statement getting the desire result?

As per me,In case `[[ -f $filename ]]` evaluates false ,then one statement of `&&` is false then result of and is false.Now it goes to OR and if first operand is 0 it returns result of second operand so it should return 1,but instead it is returning 0.

How is this being evaluated?

Comment: this is shell, not unix per se. you must misheard something: `0` is "true" and everything else is "false," so the function should return 0 if the file exists, which it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `return` statements on that last line of the function can be removed.

```
[[ -f "$filename" ]]
```

This is the last statement in the function with both `return`'s removed (note the quoted variable expansion and the added space before `]]`).  The "exit value" of the function will be the result of this statement.

If the file `$filename` exists, the function will exit with a value of zero (signifying "success", "yes", "ok" etc.), otherwise it will exit with a value of one (or more generally, non-zero, signifying "failure" of some kind).

---

Don't mix `||` and `&&` on the same line unless you know what it does.  In a command line as

```
command1 && command2 || command3
```

the last command would be executed if *either* of the previous commands failed (returned non-zero).

It's better to write

```
if command1; then
    command2
else
    command3
fi
```

*if* this is what you meant.

This matters in commands like

```
[[ -f "$filename" ]] && echo "exists" || touch "$filename"
```

This would try to execute the `touch` command if the `echo` failed, which it may do if there's nowhere to output the string to (a write error occurs).

Comment: ok.i was under impression that if [[ -f $filename ]] is able to find file it returns 1 else 0 because i executed on piece of code and it worked fine....if [- f $filename]then echo "File exist" else echo "not exist" fi...

Comment: @rahulsharma As user 'hop' commented on your question, zero means "true".  This is because the exit status of functions and utilities in general should be able to report more nuanced error conditions. Look at the manual of `rsync`, for example and look for "EXIT VALUES" in there.

Comment: Thanks.I got now.In case file exists,function abc will return 0.Now in case i call this function abc and with if statement i check :- if ( abc filename )  then do this else do that fi. So if file exists then abc will return 0,but how is if statement is getting succeed in case return  value is coming as 0?

Comment: @rahulsharma It's the same thing there. `if functionname filename; then dosomething; else somethingelse; fi` will execute `dosomething` if the file exists (the function returns 0), and it will execute `somethingelse` if the file does not exist (the function returns non-zero).

Comment: if function returns 0 ,it means if statement will understand that 0 exit code means success,so dosomething will be evaluated.Am i correct?

Comment: @rahulsharma That is a correct understanding.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have been struggling with this a lot.I thought it would be simple as C language where 0 means fail and 1 means success,but its a different story here

Comment: @rahulsharma Maybe it would help if you stopped thinking in terms of return values and instead thought of it as "success" and "failure".  An `if` statement will go into the first branch on "success" and into the `else` branch on "failure".  It's uncommon to actually look at the integer that a function or program returns.

Comment: Yeah.Correct...